# server listens to multiple ports c

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I need to example to a program for an single thread server that

listen to multiple ports in c (linux red-hut) ?

should if use one socket?

Answer (score 6):

You can't bind to multiple ports, thus you can't listen either. You need to use one socket per port.

It shouldn't be hard to do so. Simply `bind(2)` multiple sockets, `listen(2)` on each of them and add them into a `select(2)` loop.